# Model State is false, error message shows the ImageUrl is null.....here is the controller code and view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ArticleId,ArticleAuthorId,IsActive,Name,Desription,ImageUrl")] ArticleDM articledm)
{
  var errors = ModelState
               .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
               .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
               .ToArray();

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    articledm.ArticleId = Guid.NewGuid();
    db.Article.Add(articledm);                  
    HttpPostedFileBase ArtImgUrl = Request.Files["ArtImgUrl"];
    if (ArtImgUrl != null && ArtImgUrl.ContentLength > 0)
    {
      string fileDatetime = Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now.Month
        + "" + System.DateTime.Now.Day + "" 
        + System.DateTime.Now.Year + "" + System.DateTime.Now.Hour + "" 
        +  System.DateTime.Now.Minute + "" + System.DateTime.Now.Second);
      string fileName = ArtImgUrl.FileName;
      articledm.ImageUrl = "~/ArticleImages/" + fileDatetime + fileName;
      ArtImgUrl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ArticleImages/" + fileDatetime + fileName));
  }     
  db.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and view code is

```
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ArticleAuthorId, "ArticleAuthorId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageUrl, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="file" name="ArtImgUrl" id="file" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and the model is

```
public class ArticleDM : ArticleImage
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] [Key]
  public Guid ArticleId { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("ArticleAuthor")] [Column(Order = 1)]
  public Guid ArticleAuthorId { get; set; }
  public ArticleAuthorDM ArticleAuthor { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleImage
{
  public ArticleImage();
  [Required]
  public string Desription { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Model.state=false and the error code on debugging shows the ImageUrl value = `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: description and imageurl are in generic lib...                                                    public class ArticleImage
    {
        public ArticleImage();

        [Required]
        public string Desription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Please learn to format and edit your questions

Comment: You have not created a control (e.g. `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageUrl)`) for property `ImageUrl` (only a label) so nothing will post back at it will be `null` causing `ModelState` to be invalid

Comment: thanks alot it worked...because in generic lib Url field is required....but how to put url in textbox using upload control we have created???

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. Just guessing, but I assume your uploading a file which I assume you save on the server somewhere, so at that point (in the view) you don't know the url where it can be downloaded from (you don't actually set in until your post back (i.e. `articledm.ImageUrl = "~/ArticleImages/" + fileDatetime + fileName;`). You really should be creating a view model (say `CreateImageVM`) that contains only the properties you want to edit (and get rid of that awful `[Bind(Include="..")]` :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke please post it as answer.... thanks i forgot to tell when i finished after 2 days.....sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not render a form control for property `ImageUrl`, just a `<label>` element, so when you submit, the value of `ImageUrl` is `null` and `ModelState` is invalid because of the `[Required]` attribute.

Include a control for the property so its value is sent to the controller when you submit, for example

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageUrl) // or @Html.HiddenFor()
```